# Using AuthenticationForm in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm attempting to use the AuthenticationForm form with django and finding out that I can't seem to get the form to validate.  I widdled it down to a simple test(assuming it's correct) that doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone see a problem here?

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
>>> POST = { 'username': 'test', 'password': 'me', }
>>> form = AuthenticationForm(POST)
>>> form.is_valid()
False
```

Is there a real reason it won't validate?  Am I using it incorrectly?  I've basically modeled it after django's own login view.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try:

```
form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure how I missed that in django's default view.  All my other forms I just throw POST into the instance, without using a kwarg.  Any idea what's different here?

Comment: If memory serves, the AuthenticationForm is slightly different than the others. There are a few inconsistencies here and there in Django. Typically I instantiate forms using: form = MyForm(request.POST or None)

Comment: Needs to be `AuthenticationForm(None, request.POST)`

Comment: @citynorman Keping Stack Overflow answers updated would be a full-time job.

Answer (score 26):

After a few hours spent finding "Why the hack there are no validation error?!" I run into this page: http://www.janosgyerik.com/django-authenticationform-gotchas/

AuthenticationForm 's first argument is not ***data***! at all:

```
def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

So thats why you have to pass **req.POST** to data or pass something else in the first argument. It was already stated in one of the answers here to use:

```
AuthenticationForm(data=req.POST)
```

You can also use one of these:

```
AuthenticationForm(req,req.POST)
AuthenticationForm(None,req.POST)
```

Comment: Good call on the 'data='.

Answer (score 2):

The code of is_valid function:

```
return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)


>>> form.errors
{'__all__': [u'Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive.']}
```

If you see the code of method clean of AuthenticationForm

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username and password:
        self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if self.user_cache is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive."))
        elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This account is inactive."))
    self.check_for_test_cookie()
    return self.cleaned_data
```

"The problem" is that does not exits a user with this username and passowrd

Comment: Where are you seeing this is_valid?  django.forms.BaseForm?  What version of django are you running?  I'm on 1.3.1 here.  If this is using the same backend as the django admin, I have tried with a valid user/pass...

Comment: In trunk: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L119 or in the Django 1.3.1 https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/forms/forms.py#L116

Comment: form.errors was empty.  The answer above this one has fixed the problem. at hand.  Thanks for this information, though.