# Custom Django AuthenticationForm with validation depending on prior error messages

Tags: django, django-forms

I am extending Django's AuthenticationForm in order to provide better error messaging to the user.  If login is going to fail, I want to perform an additional check on the user's input to provide a less generic message explaining to the user why login failed.

urls:py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
   'django.contrib.auth.views',
    url(r'^login/$', 'login', {'authentication_form': RemoteLoginAwareLoginForm}, name='auth_login'),
)
```

forms.py:

```
class RemoteLoginAwareLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def clean(self):
      cleaned_data = super(AuthenticationForm, self).clean()
      if self.errors:  # <==== self.errors is {}, even when login will fail
          # Perform additional checks
      return cleaned_data
```

I thought that the right way to do this was to override clean() as above, but as indicated, self.errors is empty even when I logged in with bad credentials.  I tried to override full_clean() and validate() as well, but neither got called at all.

Update:

I realize that the error I'm looking for -- that the credentials aren't valid -- doesn't come until the code actually attempts to log the user in.  I added a custom ModelBackend where I am able to catch the error...  but I am not sure how to report it back up as there is no request here.

Is the answer that this requires a custom login view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar problem on stackoverflow. But I'm not sure if it solves your problem.

[Using AuthenticationForm in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421200/using-authenticationform-in-django/21504550#21504550)