# Beginner Django: Authenticating/logging in a User

Tags: python, django, authentication

Hello! I'm having trouble with the authentication system. I've followed the documentation pretty closely, but I just can't seem to get this to work. The problem seems to be that when I call the authenticate method with my cleaned form data, it's not returning anything. It's clearly doing this in the web page (it just returns the render request at the bottom every time I submit the form), and I tried authenticating in the same way via the shell and am also returning True for 'user is None'.

I'm wondering if perhaps the problem is that I haven't included the proper middleware? My MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES are as follows:

```py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

It appears that I have everything necessary, but I'm just not sure.

In any case, here's the code for my view:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login  

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse("Good Job")
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Inactive User")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Bad Job")
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/login_form.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

And here is my very simple login_form.html template:

```py
<h1>Login</h1>

<form action="/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**UPDATE:** I have implemented the following solution:

changed the line

```py
form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
```

to

```py
form = AuthenticationForm(data = request.POST)
```

Now I am able to login via the superuser account, but username/password combinations for ordinary accounts are not recognized. If I submit the credentials for a regular user, the form is re-rendered plus the following message:

**Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.**

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2**
It turns out I had an error in my registration form such that it wasn't properly storing the password for new users registered via that form. I was doing password assignment in the constructor for a new User object, when instead you need to:

```py
User.objects.create_user('username', 'email', 'password')
```

Rookie mistake! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you debug it a bit: what are the values of `username` and `password` variables? Are they the same as you've entered in the form in the browser?

Comment: Also, you are missing `form` closing tag in the template.

Comment: Ah, thanks, the closing form tag was me forgetting to indent. Anyhow, I tried getting the values before checking to see if the form was valid and I got the following error: AttributeError at /login/: 'AuthenticationForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'. It looks as if the POST data is correct, but my form isn't validating with the is_valid() method, it seems. I'm going to update the question with some of that information.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421200/using-authenticationform-in-django.

Comment: As detailed in the comment below, I've done that implementation, but now instead of simply re-rendering my template, it re-renders the template with the message: "Please enter a correct username and password etc". This is a step in the right direction, but why isn't it recognizing the correct username and password combination?

Comment: Okay, here's another update: I can login successfully via the form now via the superuser account, but not any of the other non-su accounts. Updating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `form = AuthenticationForm(data = request.POST)`

From the [django git](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py) for  AuthenticationForm:

```
def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
            """The 'request' parameter is set for custom auth use by subclasses.
                The form data comes in via the standard 'data' kwarg.`

            """
```

Comment: Okay, I've implemented that solution. I actually get a slightly different result in that I get the message: Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive when the page is rendered again after the submission. The problem is, I'm entering a correct username and password.

Comment: See question update. I can login via superuser now, but not as a regular user.

Comment: See second question update. I'm a dummy, wasn't calling the appropriate method (User.objects.create_user) in my user registration form, and passwords weren't being stored correctly.