# Django login form not working for custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am using Django 1.8 and have implemented a custom user model.  The user registration piece is 100% functional; I can submit a form and verify that users are created.  But I am struggling with the user login process.

The login form renders just fine, but when I enter a username and password that I have verified is registered (verified via the Django admin) I get to the *HttpResponse('Form is invalid')* message.

I have been stuck on this for a day or two.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**accounts/views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render

from accounts.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserLoginForm
from accounts.models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreateView(FormView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'registration/registration_form.html'
    success_url = '/connections/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(CustomUserCreateView, self).form_valid(form)


class CustomUserLoginView(FormView):
    form_class = CustomUserLoginForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    success_url = '/success/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
                )
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('User is not active') # TEMP
            else:
                return HttpResponse('User does not exist') # TEMP
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is invalid') # TEMP
```

**accounts/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    model = CustomUser
    # TODO - need to provide error message when no user is found


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile_number')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match!')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421200/using-authenticationform-in-django) ultimately led me to the fix.

In the 'post' method I needed to change the line from:

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST)
```

to:

```
form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)
```

Finally, my CustomUserLoginView looks like this:

```
class CustomUserLoginView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    success_url = '/connections/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
                )
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('User is not active') # TEMP
            else:
                return HttpResponse('User does not exist') # TEMP
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is not valid') # TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that your "post" method in the "CustomUserLoginView" is not returning an HttpResponse, because you have few "pass" instead of return the correct response. Its because you do nothing in few cases then the bottom of the method is reached and by default python functions/methods return None. You are only returning the HttpResponse in one case (when the user.is_active). You should see for which branch of the "if-else"'s you are passing. You have to return an HttpResponse in all the cases (always).

Have fun!

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your answer.  I've updated my code to include HttpResponse objects at for every 'else' statement.  I also changed the authenticate value from username=form['username'] to form['email'].  I am submitting an email address and a password that I am 100% sure are valid (they work in the Django admin login) but I am seeing 'user does not exist'.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hey joe, your welcome. perfect. I dont know, the only think i would change is how your get the value from the form. you should use "form.cleaned_data['email']" and "form.cleaned_data['password']". Try it and let me know :).
Thanks.