# Why AuthenticationForm() in Django is not being valid?

Tags: django, authentication

So I've been trying to create a function in Django for users to log into their accounts. But it is *only working for super users*. When I try to log in from other accounts, it keeps resetting the password and gives error message 'Please enter a correct username and password'. However, both username and password are correct.

Data from *request.POST* is coming as a *QuerySet* (keys-'csrfmiddlewaretoken','username','password').
When I put request.POST into **AuthenticationForm()**, it is not going through '*if form.is_valid()*:' part.

What should I do to make this work? Please, can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
def log_in(request):
    form=AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password=form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                messages.info(request,'You have successfully logged in!')
                return redirect('news')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'Invalid data!') 
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid data!')           
    return render(request,'post/login.html',{'form':form})





def register_user(request):
    form=UserCreateForm
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save()
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,'Registration was successfull')
            return redirect('news')
        messages.error(request,'Try again!')   
    return render(request,'post/register.html',{'form':form})





class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','email','password1','password2']

    def save(self,commit=True):
        user=super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email=self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: The AuthenticationForm would authenticate the users directly - or just use the view directly

Comment: Please add `print(form.errors)` after you initiated the form instance in your view and post it here

Comment: @JSRB   <ul class="errorlist"><li>__all__<ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: well it seems the credentials are wrong, thus the form is invalid..

Comment: I think the problem might be in registering user. can you please post registering the user function.

Comment: @JSRB The interesting thing is it works for superusers

Comment: @FabianClemenz Like how?

Comment: Just posted the codes. I have no problem with signing up. But once you log out you can't log in

Comment: @diyara I only found AuthenticationForm in Django 1.8 documentation - do you use this directly from Django or did you write it yourself? And is `form.is_valid()` called when you log in a superuser ?

Comment: @FabianClemenz yes, I used it directly from django and the form is validated when I try to log in a superuser

Comment: @diyara i found that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421200/using-authenticationform-in-django could you try it? As mentioned earlier the AuthenticationForm already performs the authentication, so you have a authenticated user in `form.user_cache` after clean method.

Comment: @FabianClemenz yes,I see. But I can't seem to get the form to validate with AuthentificationForm. I am getting this error - <AuthenticationForm bound=True, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;password)>> when printing form.non_field_errors.Thanks, btw

Answer (score 0):

with following code (`django 4.0.6`), i was able to get a user logged in:

```
def log_in(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(None, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.clean()
            user = form.get_user()
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
            else:
                print("nay")
        else:
            print("ney")
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

your login method should be look like this:

```
def log_in(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(None, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.clean()
            user = form.get_user()
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                messages.info(request,'You have successfully logged in!')
                return redirect('news')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'Invalid data!') 
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid data!')           
    return render(request,'post/login.html',{'form':form})
```

the `AuthenticationForm` already performs `authenticate` in its clean step - so you don't have to do that. Just call `clean` and after that the `get_user` function

PS: Keep in mind, your user must be active -> `user.is_active` must be True

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `request` from the `AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)`. The `AuthenticationForm()` function doesn't requires two arguments