# If users log out will their status change?

Tags: django, authentication, status

In django, if a user logs out, will their status change from 'active' to 'not active?

Please, I really need to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. "Active" means whether they are allowed to log in or not: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active

Comment: @deceze Can I ask you one more question? What can be the reasons why AuthenticationForm() doesn't validate credentials. But the credentials are all valid.

Comment: @diyara you need to provide more info about your problem with validation, you supposed to create new question for it

Comment: @oruchkin [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72843711/why-authenticationform-in-django-is-not-being-valid?noredirect=1#comment128668477_72843711)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the predecessors, the active field applies strictly to the account.

If you want to store information whether a user is `logged in`, you can add a `field` in the user model. Then, in the model logic, set the appropriate status depending on the activity of the user.